# Android Studio and lint.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I want to create a *lint.xml* file and share it on our VCS so all the project's contributors can use it. The [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) states:

> If you are configuring lint preferences in Android Studio, the *lint.xml* file is automatically created and added to your Android project for you

It does **not** for my project. I do not know where it saves the changes that I make to the inspections. If I click on Prefercens => Editor => Inspections => Export, then it exports a totally different file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inspections version="1.0">
  <option name="myName" value="Blabla" />
</inspections>
```

instead of lint's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
  <issue id="UnusedResources">
  <ignore ... />
  </issue>
</lint>
```

I would like to control my warnings in the IDE **and** if I click "Analyze => Inspect Code", in one place that can be shared on the VCS. Is that possible?

Comment: You are exporting IntelliJ inspections for code analysis, not lint, not sure what you are looking for

Comment: So that's two things that cannot be combined? I will have to setup two files that mostly contain the same ignore statements?

Comment: I'm fairly certain what you exported is just an [IntelliJ inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections.html). They may be similar, but the `lint.xml` is a separate thing.

Comment: @Frank Please note there is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206571) for the *lint.xml* **not** being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing IntelliJ inspection settings is better it seems, it includes lint AND the extra IntelliJ inspections both, instead of just lint.

You can export and import IntelliJ inspection settings in Android Studio, and then share it with your team mates.